# Storing sum of multiple columns in individual variables

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my code.

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(col_1) as col_1_sum FROM table_1";
        $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            $col[1] = $rows['col_1_sum'];
        }
```

I would like to know what would be the most efficient way to get the sum of say 9 more columns and store each of them in different variables,
Like the sum of the 2nd row in $col[2] and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your sql like this

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(col_1) as col_1_sum ,sum(col_2) as col_2_sum, sum(col_3) as col_3_sum  FROM table_1";
```

and fetch

```
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            $col[1] = $rows['col_1_sum']; // in here its better to start this $col[] array's index from 0 
            $col[2] = $rows['col_2_sum'];
            $col[3] = $rows['col_3_sum'];
        }
```

or like this $col array start from 0th index

```
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
                $col[0] = $rows['col_1_sum']; // in here its better to start this $col[] array's index from 0 
                $col[1] = $rows['col_2_sum'];
                $col[2] = $rows['col_3_sum'];
            }
```

Comment: if you are happy with the answer mark it as the answer

Comment: This is useful but isn't there a more efficient way, like using variables in the sql or something?

Comment: to do that you will need to use stored procedure

Comment: How would I do that? never heard of it before.

Comment: you will have to use  sql like a programming language to do your tasks the way you define it

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use 2D array to keep it as single variable

```
$variable[row_index][col_index] = $rows[col_index];
```